# Set custom grid lines

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am creating a plot in Matlab with a logarithmic x-scale. When I turn the grid lines on, it creates verticle lines with steps of 10^0.1 (figure 1). I only want ticks every 10^1.

I've tried using `set(gca,'xtick',10.^[-3:2])`, which does not change anything. I can set most of the ticks I want (Figure 2), but as soon as I add a tick at 10^-2, all of the smaller grid lines appear as well.

**Is there a way to get the gridlines I want without plotting them manually?**

Figure 1

[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
grid minor;
```

It should get rid of the minor grid lines that you don't want.

Comment: That almost did it. That turns the verticle minor lines off, but turns the horizontal lines on. I would like them to _both_ be off.

Comment: @DavidK Try `set(gca,'YGrid','off')`

Comment: I figured it out: `set(gca,'xminortick','off')` For some reason I had to do it twice for it to work. Also, if I save the figure, it does not hold when I reload it.

Answer (score 0):

It works with the next commands:

set(gca,'ygrid','on')

set(gca,'xgrid','on')

set(gca,'yminorgrid','off')

set(gca,'xminorgrid','off')